# MySQL: How to group data per hour and get the latest hour

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping

I'm trying to do a query that fetches data per `hour` but instead of the normal group by hour I want to narrow it down and only get the `latest` hour - meaning the newest data within that hour. With the picture shown below what I wanted to get is the rows with red boxes. If you will notice, first red row is `10:59:51` which means it's the only row that's within `10:00:00` and `10:59:59`. For the rest of the rows that is on `12:00` and above I wanted to get `12:37:14` because it's the latest or newest for that hour range.

[image]

I have a simple query that groups the data by `hour` using `HOUR()` like:

```
SELECT userid, username, date_created
FROM user_accounts 
WHERE date_created >= '2009-10-27 00:00:00' AND date_created < '2009-10-27 23:59:59'
GROUP BY HOUR(date_created)
```

The query, however, is just grouping it by hour `10` and `12` which returns id `24` and `25` - but what I needed is **id** `24` and `28`. Any ideas?

Comment: also try with  my answer; it is optimized

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT  f.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  MAX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_created)) AS mts
        FROM  user_accounts 
        GROUP BY HOUR(date_created)
        ) s
JOIN    user_accounts  f
ON      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_created) = s.mts
WHERE  DATE(date_created) = '2009-10-27'
```

Comment: This returned only one row for `2009-10-27` and not what I expect.

Comment: Yup, just now. Just one row out of the 5 rows I have for `2009-10-27`.

Comment: @diEcho +1 - This query is the most elegant - it will work with timestamps that are changed on updates too (id's would then not be a suitable method for finding the most recent entry within an hour). Thank you for this!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this will work?

```
SELECT userid, username, date_created
FROM user_accounts 
WHERE userid IN (
  SELECT MAX(userid)
  FROM user_accounts 
  WHERE date_created >= '2009-10-27 00:00:00' AND date_created < '2009-10-27 23:59:59'
  GROUP BY HOUR(date_created)
)
```

Comment: You can't assume MAX(id) means MAX(date_created), especially when you can just use MAX(date_created) without the need for a nested query!

Comment: Awesome! I never thought of using a sub-select and by using `MAX` you can actually get the highest ID within the grouped `HOUR(date_created)`. I tried this and it works, thanks! :)

Comment: @Gordon Murray Dent, in the context of the data, the user ID is an auto-incremented value to the table and never out of sequence to when it was actually created... so Yes, it CAN be directly implied the last user ID for a given hour WOULD work.

Comment: THIS WILL  not work if a lower id have greater time then higher id on same date: suppose `id=27` have time `12:37` and `id=28` have `12:34`

Comment: @diEcho it's an auto-increment so higher IDs always get the newer date/time. There's no way a lower ID can have a higher ID since every insert it will have a latest date/time.

Comment: @tradyblix that was not mentioned in OP, anyway my solution is fit for any situation

Answer (score 1):

I would have to assume you would also want it by day too if spanning multiple days, otherwise a max() by an hour could give you something from a week ago with one hour vs three days ago another, and current day with yet another... That, all if you spanned outside your WHERE clause specifically limiting to your single day range.  Its not by specific user you want, but whoever had the last activity for that hour... could be the same person, could be completely different every time.  I'm tacking on the specific date as part of my group test just in case you ever wanted to span a date range, but you can take it out too...

```
select STRAIGHT_JOIN
       ui.userid,
       ui.username,
       ui.date_created
   from 
       ( select
               date( date_created ),
               hour( date_created ),
               max( date_created ) as LastPerHour
            from
               user_accounts
            where
               date( date_created ) = '2009-10-27'
            group by
               date( date_created), 
               hour( date_created )) PreQuery
      join user_accounts ui
         on PreQuery.LastPerHour = ui.date_created
```

Again, I've included date as a grouping too if you wanted to span multiple days, just make sure your table has an index on date_created by itself... or at least in the first position of the index.

Comment: I can actually live with just using `MAX` alone but I appreciate your answer as I've tested it and working. I'll refer to your solution when time comes I needed it. +1 :)

Comment: @tradyblix, yes, I like the other solution too that only uses the max user ID per hour... but that will only work provided (as your data does) the column in question is of an auto-increment.  Now, if you were trying to find the last time someone was DOING something, such as a LOG History where user 1 was the last user in a given hour vs user 25, then this would be your solution...  I hope you understand the different context why one query vs the other.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean one hour from NOW or latest full hour?
If it's latest full hour something like this might work?

```
SELECT userid, username, date_created
FROM user_accounts 
WHERE HOUR(date_created) = (SELECT HOUR(date_created) FROM user_accounts ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 1);
```

EDIT:
Ahhh, now I think I get what you want... The last added entry on every given hour between your date range?

If so then Codler's query is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution

```
select date(PROCESS_DATE),hour(PROCESS_DATE),EVENT,COUNT(*) from statistics group by EVENT,date(PROCESS_DATE),time(PROCESS_TIME) order by 1 desc, 2 desc limit 1;
```

Hope this assists someone.