# Get result in a one hour interval

Tags: mysql, intervals

I have a table that looks like this

```
+--------------------+-------+
| Date/Time          | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| 2014-01-01 8:30:10 |  10   |
| 2014-01-01 8:30:05 |  11   |
| 2014-01-01 7:15:04 |  24   | 
| 2014-01-01 7:00:01 |  15   |
| 2014-01-01 6:55:20 |  06   | 
| 2014-01-01 6:30:10 |  38   |
+--------------------+-------+
```

And I'd want to get the values of that day but in a hour interval, how should I do it?
I'd want the result to be something like this:

```
+--------------------+-------+
| Date/Time          | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| 2014-01-01 8:30:10 |  10   |
| 2014-01-01 7:15:04 |  24   | 
| 2014-01-01 6:55:20 |  06   | 
+--------------------+-------+
```

Comment: So you want the latest row each hour?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137024/mysql-how-to-group-data-per-hour-and-get-the-latest-hour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT x.* 
 FROM my_table x 
 JOIN 
    ( SELECT MAX(dt) max_dt 
        FROM my_table 
       GROUP BY DATE(dt),HOUR(dt)
    ) y
   ON y.max_dt = x.dt;
```

Note that this assumes that dt is PRIMARY (or at the very least UNIQUE)

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecb9b/18)