# Only return one record per hour over a time period in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have written a Rails 4 app that accepts and plots sensor data. Sometimes there are 10 points per hour (but this number is not fixed). I'm plotting the data and doing a simple query of Points.all to get all the data points.

In order to reduce the query size, I would like to only return one record per hour. It doesn't matter which record is returned. The first record each hour using the created_at field would be fine.

How do I construct a query to do this?

Comment: Where do you store data? How does table look like.

Comment: It is in mySql in production and Sqlite in development. The class name is Point using the standard rails timestamps. So Point.create_at would return the datetime the object was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get first one, but maybe average value is better. All you need to do is to group it by hour. I am not 100% about sqlite syntax but something in this sense:

```
connection.execute("SELECT AVG(READING_VALUE) FROM POINTS GROUP BY STRFTIME('%Y%m%d%H0', CREATED_AT)")
```

Comment: Would that work in rails? I'm used to something like Point.where(....) in my query syntax

Comment: @bodagetta It'll work, so long as it is placed in the model (since connection belongs to active record base). I believe the "pure" AR version would be: `Point.average(:reading_value).group("strftime('%Y%m%d%H0', created_at")` *(untested)*

Comment: Looks legit to me, in true "Rails" way.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6137225/877472), here is an alternative which retrieves the latest record in that hour (if you don't want to average):

```
Point.from(
           Point.select("max(unix_timestamp(created_at)) as max_timestamp")
                .group("HOUR(created_at)") # subquery
          )
     .joins("INNER JOIN points ON subquery.max_timestamp = unix_timestamp(created_at)")
```

This will result in the following query:

```
SELECT `points`.* 
FROM (
      SELECT max(unix_timestamp(created_at)) as max_timestamp 
      FROM `points` 
      GROUP BY HOUR(created_at)
     ) subquery 
INNER JOIN points ON subquery.max_timestamp = unix_timestamp(created_at)
```

You can also use `MIN` instead to get the first record of the hour, if you like, as well.

Comment: I got this error !! #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: unix_timestamp: SELECT "points".* FROM (SELECT max(unix_timestamp(created_at)) as max_timestamp FROM "points"  GROUP BY HOUR(created_at)) subquery INNER JOIN points ON subquery.max_timestamp = unix_timestamp(created_at)>